# Fullcalendar nowIndicator

Tags: javascript, html, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-5

I have a problem when setting up `nowIndicator` in Fullcalendar.
When I specify:

```
slotDuration: "01:00:00"
```

the timeline is only updated every hour. But if I define it with

```
slotDuration: "00:30:00"
```

everything is working, and now the line is displaying the actual time.
Any ideas how to fix this?

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
  var calendarEl = document.getElementById("calendar");

  var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
    initialView: "resourceTimeline",
    nowIndicator: true,
    slotDuration: "01:00:00",
    slotLabelInterval: "01:00:00",
    snapDuration: "00:01:00",
    weekends: false,
    duration: { days: 14 },
  });

  calendar.render();
});
```

[Example of the problem](https://codepen.io/simonnils123/pen/KKBoMLr?editors=001)

BR
Leo

I tried to change slotDuration as described.

Comment: Personally I don't see how we could fix that for you, it seems to be an internally-programmed feature of fullcalendar. I can't see that you've done anything wrong in your configuration code. I would suggest following the bug report instructions at https://fullcalendar.io/reporting-bugs